# Articles and Concepts of Specific & General in the relative clause

Tags: grammar, articles, punctuation, relative-clauses

Which one of these options is grammatically correct?

> 1. Parents try to prepare children for **school where** their literacy skills are further developed.
> 2. Parents try to prepare children for **school, where** their literacy skills are further developed.
> 3. Parents try to prepare children for **the school where** their literacy skills are further developed.

According to grammar books, I believe that the first one is wrong while other two options are both correct, and the reason is that in the second sentence, where clause is **none-identifying** and therefore school does not need article "the", but in the third sentence "the" is needed as the where clause is identifying and we are talking about specific schools.

Comment: Yes: note that you can also say "Parents try to prepare children for a school where their literacy skills are further developed".

Comment: The first version would be more idiomatic either with plural *(**for schools**)*, or with an article *(**for a school**)*. Other than that, all three are "correct". The difference is ***they mean different things***.